# "Precise" sample timing in cycles in ios

Tags: ios, nstimer, timing, sampling

I'm periodically sending data to an RC helicopter, at the moment I am using NSTimer with a time interval of 30 ms to do this. Now due to the imprecision of NSTimer and the non-real timedness of ios I'm getting quite big discrepancies with the sample times. (5 packets of data in the first 30 ms then nothing for 4 cycles and such). Is there a more precise way to handle data sampling and timing of functions in ios?

Comment: Did you try to schedule the timer on the run-loop of a secondary thread, yet? (I.e. not creating the timer using `-scheduledTimerWith…`)

Comment: P.S. You said “I'm periodically sending data”: what mechanism do you use to do so?

Comment: Basically I'm just calling a send function with a timer every 30ms or so of an UDPClient I got from github. Data gets sent but the timing is not "fluent", as in sometimes it sends 4-6 packets in 30ms then waits for that 4-6*30ms amount of time. Erm I'm still a noob with threads and timers, what other way is there to create a timer?

Comment: There are, e.g. the `+timerWithTimeInterval:…` class-methods, and the there’s `NSTimer`’s designated initializer, all of which return an instance that isn’t scheduled on any runloop, giving you finer control. What I'm wondering is, whether your problem really is related to NSTimer or that you may be clogging the transport layer. After all, you’re attempting to send packets at 150-200Hz…

Comment: I was wondering on that too a lot but I think if it would clog the transport layer then the lagging would be more consistent and not just  let's say once every 1-2 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like you usually do in games to finely tune fps (and also keep logic and painting separate to make it work fine in any fps). Something like this, and call it in a background thread:

```
- (void)updateLoop
{
    NSTimeInterval last = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSTimeInterval elapsed = 0;
    while (self.running) {
        NSTimeInterval now = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
        NSTimeInterval dt = now - last;

        elapsed += dt;

        if (elapsed >= YOUR_INTERVAL) {
            //Do stuff
            elapsed = 0;
        }

        last = now;

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.001]; //There is not NSThread yield
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out when I get home. Erm might be a silly question but why the sleepForTimeInterval at the end? Won't it just "lag" the thread it's used on?

Comment: it's a ghetto thread yield(); Otherwhise you'll have a while(true) and it will eat 100% of your processor. it won't lag the thread, believe me. If you're curious, print elapsed and see how often the loop goes round, it'll probably be 1ms or less. Add more decimals to the 0.001 if you want, I don't know what precision it takes.

Comment: @FernandoMazzon isn’t that code you posted just a ghetto `NSRunLoop`? If so, why not just use The Real Thing(TM)?

Comment: Tried this and it solved the timing issues in the debugger, the problem still persist tho so I guess it has something to do with clogging the data layer after all. Not sure what to do with that :(.